# $state.go and $state.otherwise malfunction

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to go to a page(template) using `$state.go`.

**Controller**

```
.controller('NavCtrl', function($scope, $location, $state) {
    $scope.openDaily = function() {
        $state.go('daily');
    };
})
```

It works but for only a millisecond or something as it's redirected BACK to the `'/select'` page because the `$state.otherwise` says so.

**app.js**

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('select', {
            url: '/select',
            templateUrl: 'templates/select.html',
            controller: 'selectController'
        })
        .state('daily', {
            url: '/daily',
            templateUrl: 'templates/daily.html',
            controller: 'dailyController'
        });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/select');
})
```

What is causing this please?

UPDATE

**index.html**

```
<body ng-app="starter" animation="slide-left-right-ios7">
    <ion-nav-view>
    </ion-nav-view>
</body>
```

**select.html**

```
<ion-view title="Select" ng-controller="NavCtrl">
  <ion-content>
    <div class="list-card" ng-click="openDaily()">
      <a href='#' class="item item-icon-left">
        <i class="icon ion-home"></i>
        Personal
      </a>
    </div>
  </ion-content>

      <div class="bar bar-footer bar-balanced">
        <div class="title">Add File/Folder</div>
      </div>


</ion-view>
```

and daily.html(template):

```
<ion-view title="Select" ng-controller="NavCtrl">
</ion-view>
```

Using Ionic Framework.

Comment: you have `ng-click="openDaily()"` on anchor tag? could you add the usage of `openDaily ` in question

Comment: can you update your question with the `html` snippet too?

Comment: Implement a state change error handler in your run block and get more details there as to what problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remove `href='#'` from `<a>` tag. Because this will call default state(Here it is `select` state).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a cache problem, because everything looks correct, make sure the file is changed on you browser inspector and anything is broken on the console.

P.S: You can use also `ui-sref="daily"`, if you just want go to the page.

Comment: Useful addition